# List of Fourier series

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series, book-recommendation

For a $2\pi$-periodic function $f$ we can write down it's Fourier series
$$A_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \sin(nx) +B_n \cos(nx).$$
Is there a book or paper with a list of all function and it's corresponding Fourier series?

There are some texts with lots of examples (e.g. [here](https://library.ku.ac.ke/wp-content/downloads/2011/08/Bookboon/Calculus_and_Complex_Functions/calculus-4c-1.pdf)), but is there somewhere a more complete list?